# Can't install Ubuntu 12.04 - No available partitions

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I am unable to install Ubuntu 12.04 because it cannot recognize the partition.  More technically: "**Partition table entries are not in disk order**"

When I try to install and reach the partitioning step, I get nothing -- I mean, no partitions in the installation windows. I can't push continue because I didn't select anything. It says sdb as a disk, but with no partitions on it.

How can I get the install to acknowledge the partition?

Here's my fdisk -lu output:

```
Disk identifier: 0xbbc58b91
 
    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
 /dev/sdb1   *        2048     1607679      802816    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
 /dev/sdb2         1607680   432273407   215332864    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
 /dev/sdb3       946051072   976771071    15360000   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
 /dev/sdb4       432273408   946051071   256888832   83  Linux
 
 Partition table entries are not in disk order
 
 Disk /dev/sdc: 31.0 GB, 30992891904 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track,
 3768 cylinders, total 60532992 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 =
 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O
 size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier:
 0x0217934c
 
    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
 /dev/sdc1   *          63    60532991    30266464+   c  W95 FAT32
 (LBA)
```

Comment: What happens when you try to install Ubuntu 12.04? What kind of error message do you receive when you reach the partitioning step?

Comment: Nothing. I mean, no partitions in the installation windows. I can't push continue because i didn't select anything.
It says sdb as a disk but with no partitions on it.
Thanks!